# Problems with a function to sum various elements in a nested data structure in R

Tags: r, function, nested, pipe

I try to create a simple function how to sum some variables in a nested data set.

Here is a much simpler example

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),
var=c("A","B","C","D","B","A","D","A","C","D","D","D","A","D","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
N=c(50,50,50,50,298,156,156,85,85,85,278,301,98,98,98,98,98,98,98,98))
```

Think of this as a dataframe containing results of 7 different studies. Each study has investigated one or more Variables (A, B, C, D). The variables mean

ID = The ID of a respective study.

var = The respective variable measured in each study. Some studies have measured only one variable (e.g., ID=2, which only contained b), some several

N = The sample size of each study. That is, each ID has a sample size

I would like to create a function that summarizes three things:

k = how many studies measured each variable (e.g., "A")

m = how often each variable was measured (regardless whether some studies measured a variable more than once)--a simple frequency.

N = the sample size per variable--but only once per study. That is, no duplications per study ID are allowed.

My current version (I am a real noob, so please forgive the form), results in exactly what I want:

```
  model    km   N
1     A 4 (7) 389
2     B 3 (5) 446
3     C 2 (2) 135
4     D 6 (6) 968
```

For instance, variable A was measured 7times, but only by 4 studies (i.e., study #7 measured it several times. The (non-redundant) sample size was N=389 (not counting the several measures of study #7 more than one time).

(Note: The parentheses in the table are helpful as I intend to copy the results into a document)

Here is the current version of the code. The problems begin with the part containing the pipes

```
kmn <- function(data, x, ID, N) {
  m <-table(data[[x]]) 
  k <-apply(table(data[[x]],data[[ID]]), 1, function(x) length(x[x>0]) )
  model <- levels(data[[x]])
  km <- cbind(k,m)
  colnames(km)<-c("k","m")
  km <- paste0(k," (",m,")") 
  smpsize <- data %>% 
    group_by(data[[x]]) %>% 
    summarise(N = sum(N[!duplicated(ID)])) %>% 
    select(N)
  cbind(model,km,smpsize)  
}

kmn(data=df, x="var", ID = "ID", N="N")
```

The above code works but only if the df-dataframe really contains the N-variable (but not with a different variable name). I guess the "data %>%" prompts R to look into the dataframe and not to use the "sum(N..." part as reference to the call.

I can guess that this looks horrible for someone with some idea :)

Thank you for any ideas 
Holger

Comment: Take a look in group_by and summarize functions from dplyr. They are very handy in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove duplicates by using the `unique` function and sum by `var`.

Secondly take `df` and group by `var`, `n()` gives the count and `n_distinct(ID)` the number of unique IDs, then you join the dataframe `stats_N`

```
library(dplyr)

stats_N <- df %>% 
  select(ID,var,N) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(N))

df %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(),km=n_distinct(ID)) %>% 
  left_join(stats_N)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  var       n    km     N
#  <fct> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         7     4   389
#2 B         5     3   446
#3 C         2     2   135
#4 D         6     6   968
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the @fmarm's answer, it can be also done without a join, where do the group by 'var', get the number of distinct elements in 'D' (`n_distinct`), number of rows (`n()`) and the `sum` of non-duplicated 'N's

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(model = var) %>%
  summarise(km = sprintf("%d (%d)", n_distinct(ID), n()), 
          N = sum(N[!duplicated(N)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  model km        N
#  <fct> <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     4 (7)   389
#2 B     3 (5)   446
#3 C     2 (2)   135
#4 D     6 (6)   968
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am absolutely thrilled. I recently discovered dplyr but I was not aware that it is so powerful. However, I do not understand most of the arguments ("sprintf", "%d" etc.). Do you have some kind of recommendation where I could move to learn more about the possibilities?

Comment: @HolgerSteinmetz  Glad too know you are liking it.  `sprintf` is a base R function similar to the one in various other languages (format or f string -python) an where it gives an output back while formatting the input based.  here, `%d` suggests the input argument to be digit.  With `%d (%d)`, it is basically changing the format by adding the `()` and pasteing the two arguments (`n_distinct`, `n()`) to a single string.  I would first read the dplyr vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html)